# How to know if a promise inside a loop has ended?

Tags: javascript

First of all, I'm sorry if this is a basic question, but I am not being able to do this. 
I have a promise that inserts data into a table (sqlite), and I have a for iterating over an array. I want to put all of that data into the table, but I want to know when it ends, to display a message at the end. I was verifying (*i == array.length -1*) it displayed the message but that doesn't seem correct. If I don't do this in this way the message displays before it has ended. 
I have two other promises that should run along this one and the solution(it seems a bad solution) above wouldn't work in this case, because one can end after or before the iteration. How can I know when they all are done too? 
Could you help me, please?

Here's my code:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < this.data_array.length; i++) {
    this.database.insertService(this.data_array[i]).then(async () => {
         console.log('Inserting object number ' + this.data_array[i].id);
           if( i == this.data_array.length - 1) {
              console.log('done!');
           }
     }).catch(err => console.log('error inserting object into the table'));
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's 100% guaranteed that if you ave a loop that fires async operations, then the loop will *always* finish before any of the Promises is resolved

Comment: so if I delete the async everything works out?

Comment: @memyselfandi No, because the promise is still asynchronous regardless. If the outer scope is also async and you are ok with the promises executing sequentially you could `await` the promise, otherwise you'll have to use another method.

Comment: The first thing I see  that is wrong with the updated code is `this.data_array.map` should not be surrounded around `[]`

`Promise.all(this.data_array.map...` as map will return a new array already

Comment: I did that because it's an array of promises. is that wrong? how should I add the other ones then?

Comment: I made a simple example of what your code seems to be:
https://repl.it/repls/BitterGenerousPython

Also you can remove all `catch` and `then` inside the `all() ` as they will be handled in the final then/catch.

Comment: `map` is more or less like a for loop. In your example you have something similar to `Promise.all([[promise], promise, promise. promise]`)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using `Promise.all`

Here is an [example](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-await-array-map/) and here some [useful documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

the example is using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of a for loop to iterate over the array.

I haven't tested it but that should work

```
    Promise.all(
      this.data_array.map((data) => {
        console.log('Inserting object number ' + data.id);
        return this.database.insertService(data);
      })
    )
      .then((result) => console.log('done', result))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Comment: I did this and the message done appeared before it inserted all. is the code complete or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It is a better practice to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) when dealing with such cases. A simple example would be the following:

```
let i;
let promises = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
     promises.push(someAsyncFunc(i));

Promise.all(promises)
     .then((results) => {
          console.log("All done", results);
     })
    .catch((e) => {
         console.log(e)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Promise.all([])` where `.all()` take an array.

```
Promise.all(
  // Map the items in data_array to the async insertService function
  this.data_array.map(dataEntry => this.database.insertService(dataEntry))
).then((resultArray) => {
  console.log(resultArray.length);
  console.log('done!');
}).catch((e) => {
     console.log(e)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `Promise.all` is the best solution here

```js
async method() {
  const promises = this.data_array.map(item => 
  this.database.insertService(item));
  try  {
    const result = await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log({ result });
  } catch (error) {
      console.log({ error });
  }
}
```